# Multiplying x and y coordinates with different scalars?

Tags: list-manipulation

I have a list of data for which I need to multiply x-coordinates by `63` and y-coordinates by `50` inside the list. The list is in the following form:

```
a= {{x1,y1},{x2,y2},...,{xN,yN}}
```

I want the result to look like as {{x1*63,y1*50},{x2*63,y2*50},...,{xN*63,yN*50}}.  How could I do it?

Comment: A simple one-liner: `Transpose[{63,50}*Transpose[a]]`

Comment: Thank you everyone for helping me, Now i could do it based on the ideas you posted above for my question

Answer (score 11):

This should be fast, in particular if `a` is large packed array of reals ($\geq 1000000$ entries).

```
a.DiagonalMatrix[{63, 50}]
```

Answer (score 8):

Since you are interested in large lists, I summarize below the efficiencies of all the methods proposed in the answers. From the faster to the slower:

```
a = RandomReal[{0, 1}, {5 10^5,2}];

AbsoluteTiming[a.DiagonalMatrix[{63, 50}]][[1]] (*0.003058*)

AbsoluteTiming[
  (a[[;; , 1]] = a[[;; , 1]]*63;
   a[[;; , 2]] = a[[;; , 2]]*50;)][[1]] (*0.041443*)

AbsoluteTiming[Transpose[{63, 50}*Transpose[a]]][[1]] (*0.008279*)

AbsoluteTiming[Function[x, {63 x[[1]], 50 x[[2]]}] /@ a][[1]] (*0.079297*)

AbsoluteTiming[(# {63, 50}) & /@ a][[1]] (*0.083761*)

AbsoluteTiming[ScalingTransform[{63, 50}]@a][[1]] (*0.102272*)

AbsoluteTiming[Thread[{63, 50}*Thread@a]][[1]] (*0.259768*)

f[{xi_, yi_}] := {63*xi, 50*yi}; AbsoluteTiming[Map[f, a]][[1]] (*0.900141*)
```

The method proposed by @Henrik Schumacher is by far the fastest!

Comment: BTW, I have no clue why the first one is so fast respect to the others!

Comment: It's called vectorization. Modern CPUs employ [fused multiply-add](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiply–accumulate_operation#Fused_multiply–add) units that speed up vector-vector products (and thus also matrix-vector products) tremendously. Some implementations even perform a vector-product of two 4-vectors in on go. Moreover, the routines  that Mathematica uses as backend for `Dot` (I'm talking about [BLAS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_Linear_Algebra_Subprograms)-rountines `gemv` and `gemv`) are highly optimized for the hardware on which you run the code.

Comment: The lesson to learn here: Always try to describe linear operations on big arrays by `Dot`.

Comment: Moreover: Albeit also vectorized, the second methods suffers from the fact that the array `a` is internally stored in this order: `{a[[1,1]],a[[1,2]],a[[2,1]],a[[2,2]],a[[3,1]],...}` So, the read operation `a[[;; , 1]]` rips this array apart and also the write operation does `a[[;; , 1]]= ...` not go into consecutive memory locations. _Sometimes_, it is better to transpose the array first, which leads to the third method. But it is also true that `Transpose` reorders. This should involve an unnecessary memory allocation and an unnecessary copy operation.

Comment: Amazing! Thanks A LOT for the explanation :D

Comment: You're welcome.

Answer (score 5):

```
listOfPairs = {{1, 2}, {3, 4}};

(# {63,50})& /@ listOfPairs
```

> {{63, 100}, {189, 200}}

Parentheses are here only for readibility

Comment: Yes, this is it.

Answer (score 4):

Just

```
a[[;; , 1]] = a[[;; , 1]]*63;
a[[;; , 2]] = a[[;; , 2]]*50;
```

Comment: Kiara, thanks for giving me idea. But the problem is, i had too many data inside the list. a1 = {{0.82, -109}, {0.98, -75}, {1.12, -57}, {1.17, -52}, {1.30, 
-43}, {1.37, -38}, {1.45, -34}, {1.54, -30}, {1.64, -26}, {1.76, 
-22.9}, {1.95, -18.6}, {2.06, -16.6}, {2.24, -13.8}, {2.47, -11.2},
{2.74, -8.9}, {3.09, -6.8}, {3.53, -5}, {3.80, -4.17}, {4.12, -3.4},
{4.59, -2.55}, {4.94, -2.06}, {5.26, -1.70}, {5.62, -1.37}, {5.83,
-1.20}, {6.18, -0.96}, {6.51, -0.77}, {6.87, -0.58}}. How can it be done in a single thread with out separating the coordinates.

Comment: @rabink That redefines `a`, so the _new_ `a` is what you seek.

Answer (score 3):

Also

```
ScalingTransform[{63, 50}]@a
```

Comment: Surprising answer here!

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way of doing this.

You could write a little function that accepts a list {xi,yi} and returns a list {63*xi,50*yi}. That function might look like

```
f[{xi_,yi_}]:={63*xi,50*yi}
```

Then you want to do that function to every item in your list a. `Map` will "do the same thing to every item in a list. That might look like

```
Map[f,a]
```

Let's see if it works

```
a={{1,2},{7,3},{5,1}};
f[{xi_,yi_}]:={63*xi,50*yi};
Map[f,a]
```

and the result is

```
{{63,100},{441,150},{315,50}}
```

Once you get the idea of how to do this you can then learn to translate this into cryptic punctuation and save typing a couple of characters each time. There are always a dozen ways of doing anything in Mathematica and some think the goal is to use the fewest possible characters to do anything. But for a new user the goal is to understand how to do things without making mistakes or misunderstanding.

Comment: great, it works. Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

Another way:

```
list = {{1, 2}, {3, 4}};
Function[x, {63 x[[1]], 50 x[[2]]}] /@ list


(*{{63, 100}, {189, 200}}*)
```